# Django project with core code stored in an app with the same name

Tags: django

When creating a Django project (e.g. `myapp`), the framework also creates a subdirectory/python package with the same name as the project to hold `settings.py`, `urls.py` and `wsgi.py`:

```
─ myapp
  └─ myapp
     ├─ __init__.py
     ├─ settings.py
     ├─ urls.py
     └─ wsgi.py
```

Although I then add a number of apps, I almost always have some core functionality that belongs to the project itself.

Is there any reason why I should not add the core functionality to the `myapp` package alongside `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` and include this in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`? E.g.:

```
─ myapp
  ├─ app1
  ├─ app2
  └─ myapp
     ├─ __init__.py
     ├─ models.py
     ├─ settings.py
     ├─ templates
     |  └─ homepage.html
     ├─ urls.py
     ├─ views.py
     └─ wsgi.py
```

I've seen other people create a `core` app instead to hold the 'core' code that is specific to the project, is this necessary?

Comment: I think you can do it either way, it is in my opinion matter of taste. You could also place all of your apps as subdirectories of the subdirectory `myapp`, having for example `myapp.firstapp`, `myapp.secondapp`. Depending on the complexity of the project you should look for the best way to group your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just reading the Django docs for [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps) and I saw a link to "[Learn more about application configurations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/)" that answers my question:

> There’s no restriction that a project package can’t also be considered an application and have models, etc. (which would require adding it to INSTALLED_APPS).

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications